# Anyone know why ReCaptcha may be styling wrong

Tags: php, css, styles, recaptcha

Here is my page and the ReCaptcha error is obvious

http://www.bookiebashers.org/register.php

Any suggestions to why it may be stretched.  I am completly puzzled to why this may be happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In styles.css, you have the following lines:

```
#content img {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px #888 solid;
    margin: 8px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

These rules are also applied to the images within the captcha.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Been sitting here for hours puzzled.  Thanks!

Comment: @cbarlow123: On many browsers, there's an option to inspect CSS and HTML. On chrome it's built in, in FireFox there's Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

`#content img` has rules that set the width and height to unnatural values. You should be fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

I answered your same question over on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574177/recapcha-styling-messing-up/10574304#10574304

Here it is again.

This will sort your problem out, add the following to your css

```
#content .recaptchatable img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    }
```

For some reason you have the following in your css

```
#content img {
    padding: : 8px;
    border: 1px #888 solid;
    margin: 8px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    }
```

This sets the height and width for every image within the #content container. The css I provided will override this.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the `line-height` property. This fixed it:

```
.recaptchatable, #recaptcha_area tr, #recaptcha_area td, #recaptcha_area th {
    line-height: 0;
}
```